# ":target" pseudo-class when multiple "a" elements are used as destantions

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

Sometimes we may need to provide a path to a specific section on a web page using multiple different `#`-tail URLs, and for this task, as far as I know, we have to use multiple blank `<a>` elements. Here is an example:

```html
<p><a href="#sun">Lorem</a> ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem <a href="#yellow">ipsum</a> dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="#hot">sit</a> amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<a id="yellow"></a>
<a id="hot"></a>
<h1 id="sun">Sun</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

After the "jump" (that is, after the user have clicked one of the hyperlinks), I would prefer to highlight the `<h1>` element `Sun` using the `:target` pseudo-class.

But how to make it work not only for `href="sun"`, but also for `href="hot"` and `href="yellow"`?

```css
/* works for href="sun" */
:target { outline: 1px solid red; }

/* my attempt to make it work for href="hot". Doesn't work.
And there is still a question how to make it work for href="yellow" */
:target + h1 { outline: 1px solid red; }
```

Comment: `hot` and `yellow` are inline elements without any text. If you were expecting an empty outlined square, then add some text or a space entity (ex. `&nbsp;`), style it so it's `display: inline-block` or `block`, etc. Also, the proper syntax for a `href` value that jumps to an `id` is prefixed with a `#` (ex. `<a href="#sun">Go to the Sun</a>`).

Comment: Your first :target  works correctly. But like @zer00ne mentioned, you need to have something down there that has content or takes up actual space.  Like wrap each in a `section` and use H1 tags inside etc.

Comment: _"Also, the proper syntax for a href value ..."_ - Sorry, I was in a hurry. _"If you were expecting an empty outlined square"_ - No, what I expected is a red frame around `h1` element, not around empty `a`. That is, when I click `href="#yellow"`, the web page should be scrolled down to `h1` element, and there should be a red frame around `h1`, not around `a`, of course. `a` elements are just "destination points" and I don't mean to add them any visual style.

Comment: What about general sibling selector `:target ~ h1`? would it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using general sibling selector `:target ~ h1` :

```css
:target:not(a) {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

:target ~ h1 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#sun">Lorem</a> ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem <a href="#yellow">ipsum</a> dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="#hot">sit</a> amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<a id="yellow"></a>
<a id="hot"></a>
<h1 id="sun">Sun</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kosh. What is the exact reason you use `:target:not(a)` and not just `:target` here?

Comment: @yrslv2022, `:not(a)` to avoid outlining empty `<a>` which is the case in FireFox

Comment: Hmm, I don't have Firefox at hand, but this seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Be specific in terms of what has target pseudo class as in this snippet:

```html
<p><a href="#sun">Lorem</a> ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem <a href="#yellow">ipsum</a> dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="#hot">sit</a> amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<a id="yellow"></a>
<a id="hot"></a>
<h1 id="sun">Sun</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<style>
   :target,
  .hot:target+h1,
  .yellow:target+a+h1 {
    outline: 1px solid red;
  }
</style>
```

It depends on how general a solution you are seeking. Obviously it's going to be tedious putting all those +s in if there are many synonyms, so  this is maybe just a start.

Answer (score 1):

## Options

### Option A (Recommended)

Use the same `href` value. If your destination is jumping to the same area, then the extra `<a>` are pointless. If you want each destination to stop at a different position of the page and outline a particular element that'll be visible after the jump, then see **Option B**.

### Option B

Instead of using a commonly used element such as an `<a>`nchor as a jump destination, try using an inline element not commonly used (or an element you know you won't be using or at the very least used very seldom.) These blank destinations should be styled so that they are not visible to the user, see **Figure I**:

#### Figure I

```css
b {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  color: transparent;
}
```

Do not use an unspecific selector such as `:target` to select a specific element. See **Figure II**.

#### Figure II

```html
<b id="Y"></b>
<b id="Z"></b>
<h3 id="X">X</h3>
```

**Don't do this**

This will work for #X, but it'll outline #Y and #Z when the matching
link is clicked, which is completely unnecessary since the goal is to
outline only #X.

```css
:target {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

**Do this**

Specify the element that needs to be outlined. First, prefix the selector `:target` with something that specifies the primary destination.

```css
h3:target {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

Then for the blank destinations use a non-prefixed `:target` pseudo-class and a [**general sibling combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator): `~` rather than an [**adjacent sibling combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator): `+`. The `~` means: *"Apply styles to any selector to the right of `~` that follows the selector to the left of `~`"*. The `+` means: *"Apply styles to the selector directly to the right of `+` that follows the selector to the left of `+`"*.

```css
:target ~ h3 {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}

/* If there are any other <h3> that follow after then use more specific 
selectors */
  
:target ~ #X {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

### Example

```css
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI";
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

mark {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  color: transparent;
}

h2:target,
:target ~ h2 {
  outline: 3px ridge #263F32;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li><a href="#walter">Walter</a></li>
  <li><a href="#white">Mr. White</a></li>
  <li><a href="#heisenberg">Heisenberg</a></li>
</menu>
<h1>Breaking Bad</h1>
<article>
  <p>Anything suspicious? Well... then should we go? Any uh... Cartel news these days? Seems like I'm always reading something or other in the paper. I don't want to talk about it. To you or anyone else. I'm done explaining myself. Gus is dead. We've got
    work to do.</p>
  <p>Jesse Jackson? Do you even... ah, I see you have a telephone at least. You know that blinking thing I've been calling you on? I will break this, I will BREAK THIS. Damn druggie idiot. Is this what you've been doing the whole time I've been trying to
    reach you?</p>
    <p>My partner was about to get himself shot. I intervened. He was angry because those two dealers of yours had just murdered an eleven year-old boy. Then again, maybe he thought it was you who gave the order.</p>

<p>He has enough money to last forever. He knows he needs to keep moving. You'll never find him. He's out of the picture. I saved his life, I owed him that, but now he and I are done. Which is exactly what you wanted, isn't it. You've always struck me as a very pragmatic man so if I may, I would like to review options with you. Of which, it seems to me you have two.</p> 

<p>Option A, you kill me right here and now. Apparently I've made that very easy for you. You can kill me, no witnesses and then spend the next few weeks or months tracking down Jesse Pinkman and you kill him too. A pointless exercise it seems to me but that is Option A.</p>
</article>
<mark id="white"></mark>
<mark id="heisenberg"></mark>
<h2 id="walter">Bryan Cranston</h2>
<article>
  <p>The game has changed. The word is out. And you... are a killer. Apparently it's all over town. Somebody crossed you, you got angry, you crushed their skull with an ATM machine. Who cares! Just as long as it's our competitors who believe it and not the
    police.</p>
</article>
```